Match the signed-in account to the Play Store Account using Sign in with Google
Question
How might I reliably create a 1:1 connection between the Play Store account that made the purchase and the Google account signed into the app?
This would mimic the 1:1 connection that exists on iOS (explained below).
The app would allow only Sign in with Google to simplify this.

Background
If an iOS app offers Sign in with Apple, the developer may be sure that the signed-in Apple Account is necessarily the same Apple Account that made the purchase. This is because:

Sign in with Apple may use only the Apple Account currently associated the device
Only one Apple Account may be signed into the device at a time
StoreKit uses the Apple Account currently associated with the device for all purchases

One benefit to developers of the Apple approach is related to determining which content to unlock for the user. If StoreKit says the user has an active subscription, then it is necessarily the same signed-in user that made the purchase. Although the server also keeps an independent record, this allows the developer to reliably unlock content client-side without manual network requests, since StoreKit may be trusted.
On Android, the Play Store API may confirm that the current account signed into the device's Play Store has an active subscription, but this account may not be the same account signed into the app.
The problem is then knowing which signed-in user is the user that made the purchase.
For example, suppose:

A device has Google-Account-A associated with the Play Store.
A user signs into the app using Google-Account-B, and makes a purchase (which goes through Google-Account-A).
A user signs into the app, on the same device, using Google-Account-C.

In both cases, checking the Play Store API on that device would indicate that there is an active subscription, as long as Google-Account-A is signed into the Play Store. Paid features would be unlocked whether the user is signed into Google-Account-B or Google-Account-C, or any number of other accounts. This would allow many users to share a single subscription, as long as they all had access to the same Play Store account (Google-Account-A).
Essentially, I want to unlock access only for the Play Store account that made the purchase, but Sign in with Google does not necessitate that the user signs in with this account. So I need to find a way to create that connection without manually saving and updating a mapping.

Ideas

At the time of purchase, save a mapping of the Play Store account to the currently-signed in account on the server, and only unlock content for users signed in with either of those accounts. I would rather not do this, and find a way to mimic the approach on iOS, where I do not need to handle saving, updating, and periodically requesting this mapping from the server.

Require that users sign in with the device's current Play Store account.

At the time of purchase, check that the signed-in account matches the Play Store account. If so, allow the purchase. Otherwise, do not allow it and ask the user to sign in using their Play Store account.


Options #2 and #3 are similar, but #2 causes less friction since once the user is signed in, there would be no issues.
Are either of these possible? Is there a better approach?

Potential Implementation
For option #2, my guess is that the flow would be something like this:

The user signs in using Sign in with Google.
Once the sign in is authorized, check that the signed-in account matches the device's current Play Store account.
If so, continue to the app's home screen. Otherwise, sign out the user to clear the just-authorized sign in, and remain on the sign in screen with an explanation of the requirement to sign in using the Play Store account.

As long as APIs exist to perform this check, and it does not violate any of Google's rules, I think I would prefer this approach. If this is the most workable approach, what are the correct APIs to use?
Option #3 would be similar, but the check would be performed at the time of the purchase.
